# How to force all links to start with HTTP [php]

Tags: php, regex, url, hyperlink

This question is kind of hard to word, so I'll try my best.

I want every link to start with http:// if it doesn't already. Here's an example:

I want a link like `google.com` to automatically rewrite to `http://google.com`. Let me explain why. I am trying make all user written URLs into real links with Regular Expressions. I successfully got that with this expression: `/[a-z]{3,7}\:\/\/[^\<\s\"\'\>]+|[\w\-\.]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}/i` but every link that looks like this: `google.com` redirects to `http://localhost/website/google.com` which is not what I want, I want it to go to `http://google.com`.

Does that make sense?

My full PHP is here:

```
$text = "google.com";
$regex = "/[a-z]{3,7}\:\/\/[^\<\s\"\'\>]+|[\w\-\.]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}/i";
if (preg_match($regex, $text, $url)) {
    //url match
    $text= preg_replace($regex, "<a href='{$url[0]}''>{$url[0]}</a>", $text);
    echo $text;
}
```

Comment: Whats your actual url look like?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to write a regular expression to try and transform everything that *looks* like it *might* be a URL into a URL. At best it's going to flip out and make URLs out of things that aren't while missing URLs formatted in ways you didn't expect.

If you have a string that is *supposed* to be a URL, but doesn't start with `http://` simply append it.

```
$myurl = 'google.com';
if( !preg_match('@^https?://@', $myurl) ) {
  $myurl = 'http://'.$myurl;
}
```

Better yet, use input validation to ensure that bad data doesn't make it into your application in the first place.